# CA-Certificate and Server Certificate are expired! - openVPN - Server <--> Client(x)

Tags: security, vpn, openvpn, openssl

I am hosting an openVPN-Service to connect ~30 IoT-Clients directly to my Server. I have forgoten to extend the lifetime of the **self-signed** ca.cert and the server.crt. Now my openVPN-Clients could not connect anymore and i could barely reach them physically.

I have tried the following two things:

1. Create new `caNew.crt` with the old key `caOld.key`.

```shell
openssl x509 -in caOld.crt -days 36500 -out caNew.crt -signkey caOld.key
openssl verify -CAfile caNew.crt client01.crt
test.crt: OK
```

[^1](https://forums.openvpn.net/viewtopic.php?t=30545)

2. Create Server CSR

```shell
openssl req -new -key server_old.key -out serverNew.csr

openssl x509 -req -in serverNew.csr -CA ca_new.crt -CAkey ca.key -CAcreateserial -out serverNew.crt -days 500 -sha256
```

The Modolus of the old and new certs are equal - at this moment i had a little hope, but...

Replace the old direct in `server.conf` of the openVPN Server configuration to two new files, restart server.

Error LOG:

```
Wed Sep  6 12:00:13 2023 IP.IP.IP.IP:47713 TLS Error: TLS key negotiation failed to occur within 60 seconds (check your network connectivity)

Wed Sep  6 12:00:13 2023 IP.IP.IP.IP:47713 TLS Error: TLS handshake failed
```

My Questions:

Is my attempt possible? If yes, what is wrong?
If no, i think i have to do a roadtrip... :D